# Messed up my alignment horizontally using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

.I want the breakpoint at 800px to place all three review divs side by side with 20px of padding around them but for whatever reason, it's not working. Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Currently, Reviewer 1 and 2 are stacked on top of each other to the left side of the container, while Review 3 is all by it's lonesome on the right. How do I change this?

Code snippet below:

HTML:

```
      <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card-1">
      <h3>Reviewer 1</h3>
      <p class="border">
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-2">
      <h3>Reviewer 2</h3>
        <p class="border">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card-3">
        <h3>Reviewer 3</h3>
        <p class="border">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam."</p>
           </div>
  </div>
```

---

CSS:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  }



  .border {
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out ironically enough. I just changed the .wrapper div as follows:

```
    .wrapper {
     display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```